# Fatal error: Class 'RulesEventHandlerEntityBundle' not found in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I got the following fatal error in drupal. please guide me how to resolve this error with out update the rules module. because i wrote some custom rules in this module.

> Fatal error: Class 'RulesEventHandlerEntityBundle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName\sites\all\modules\rules\modules\node.rules.inc on line 147

Comment: If you have altered the rules module, you will have to implement the code in the patch on [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2090511) page

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there was an update to the module and you didn't run **update.php**.

I had the same error a few days ago when updating a Drupal Commerce project (rules module included) and I had forgotten to run the database upgrade script.

[How to use update.php (Drupal Docs)](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/running-update-php)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, download the latest version and drop it into your modules directory (or, drush dl rules).  Then update the database manually using http://yoursite/updatedb.php or drush updatedb.